# Is there a use case where you would use math.div() in SCSS/Sass instead of a calc() expression?

Tags: css, sass

For [plenty of good reasons](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div) Sass is deprecating the use of `/` as a generic division operator.

In the documentation, they list the main alternative as `math.div()` and then at the end mention that the deprecation of `/` as an operator does not affect `calc()` expressions.

From my perspective, replacing existing expressions with `calc()` is a simpler process (since you don't have to reformat the expression to use a comma nor import `sass:math`) and that it is more future proof, since Sass is a superset of CSS (i.e. `math.div()` is likely to be deprecated in Sass before `calc()` is deprecated in CSS). It's also [supported in all major browsers.](https://caniuse.com/?search=calc())

Is there any reason or use case where you would be better served by `math.div()` instead of `calc()`?

Answer (score 3):

While writing this question, it finally occurred me that because `math.div()` operates like a function, it returns a single value that is then used in the resulting CSS, as opposed to `calc()` which remains an expression that is evaluated by the browser.

The benefits of the former would be

- Supporting older browser versions in edge use cases
- Reducing the length of the resulting CSS and therefore size of the CSS
- Reducing the resources needed by the browser to apply the CSS

For the most part and in most projects, those gains are likely marginal. Better written CSS would likely have a more significant impact. But I can imagine instances where it would make a difference.

If there are other use cases where a value would be preferred to an expression, I'd love to hear from the community.

Comment: we can use CSS variables inside calc() and those variable may change based on the element. You cannot replace this using the Sass math

Comment: Re _"as opposed to `calc()` which remains an expression that is evaluated by the browser"_: Sass will [simplify `calc()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div#transition-period) down to a single number when possible. From that page: _"Alternatively, users can wrap division operations inside a `calc()` expression, which Sass will simplify to a single number."_